# Проблема с обработкой событий input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, валидация

Изначальная задача проверить все теги `input` перед отправкой на сервер. Принимаются любые предложения. Касаемо моего кода: изначально на странице всего три `input`, все три реагируют на событие `.keyup()` (использую jquery 3.3.1). Так же имеется кнопка добавления последних двух `input` (посредством `.append()`) с полями ввода стоимости и назначения соответственно (их и нужно проверить на правильность), этих добавленных полей может быть неограниченное число. После отображения их на экране, событие `.keyup()` продолжает срабатывать на первые три `input`, и категорически игнорирует 'новые' `input`. Почему так происходит? И есть ли более простые способы проверки?

Код проверки:

```js
$('input').keyup(event => {
  console.log('event', event)
  switch (event.target.className) {
    case 'newTotal':
      console.log('newTotal', event.target.value);
      break;
    case 'price':
      console.log('price', event.target.value);
      break;
    case 'title':
      console.log('title', event.target.value);
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: `$(document).on("keyup, 'input', event => {`

Comment: @Igor Спасибо огромное! Помогло! Подскажи пожалуйста, если не трудно - почему так? Или что почитать, чтобы лучше понять?

Comment: Это называется "делегирование обработки событий" - когда обработчик прикрепляется к элементу страницы (в данном случае - документу), который гарантировано существует в момент назначения обработчика. Но вызывается этот обработчик только для (и в контексте) элементов удовлетворяющих селектору во втором параметре. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Igor Супер, еще раз большое спасибо!